# Is there a way in Play JSON to define a reader for something that is not an object (/array)?

Tags: scala, play-json

Basically, I have a JSON of this shape:

```json
{
  "color": "#abcdef"
}
```

so I write a `Reads`:

```scala
import java.awt.Color

case class Options(color: Color)

((__ \ "color").read[Color])(Options _)
```

except there is no reader for `Color`. My second attempt was:

```scala
(
  Color.decode((__ \ "color").read[String])
)(Options _)
```

but that's also apparently not correct. The documentation show ways to create readers for `{ }` (and `[ ]`)'s, but not for "primitives" like numbers or strings. Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
case class Options(color: Color)

object Options {
  implicit val colorReads: Reads[Color] = __.read[String].map(Color.decode)
  implicit val optionsReads: Reads[Options] = Json.reads[Options]
}
```

Then the usage is:

```
val b = Json.parse("{ \"color\": \"#abcdef\"}").as[Options]
println(b) // prints: Options(java.awt.Color[r=171,g=205,b=239])
```

Comment: In short, do stuff on `__` directly, right?

Comment: @RubenVerg, yeap, exactly. It is already a `JsString`, so you can now manipulate it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to defined `Reads` for `Color` to be consistent with rest of Play Json infrastructure, like:

```
import scala.util._
import play.api.libs.json._
import java.awt.Color

case class Options(color: Color)

object Options {
  implicit val colorReads: Reads[Color] = {
    implicitly[Reads[String]].flatMapResult { value =>
      def invalidColor(cause: Throwable) = {
        JsError(JsonValidationError(s"Invalid color value: `$value`. Error: ${cause.getMessage}"))
      }

      def validColor(color: Color) = {
        JsSuccess(color)
      }
      Try(Color.decode(value)).fold(invalidColor, validColor)
    }
  }

  implicit val reads: Reads[Options] = Json.reads
}

val jsonString = """ { "color": "#abcdef" }""".stripMargin
/*
 * Prints out: Options(java.awt.Color[r=171,g=205,b=239])
 */
println(Json.parse(jsonString).as[Options])

val invalidColorJsonString = """ { "color": "invalid_color" }""".stripMargin

/*
 * Prints out: JsError(List((/color,List(JsonValidationError(List(Invalid color value: `invalid_color`. Error: For input string: "invalid_color"),WrappedArray()))))) 
 */
println(Json.parse(invalidColorJsonString).validate[Options])
```

Used scala: 2.12, sbt: 1.4.7, Play Json: 2.9.2

Comment: This looks way more complicated than it should be

Comment: @RubenVerg it looks like this, because of proper error handling.

Comment: Doesn't `Color.decode("sdahd")` throwing already handle correctly?

Comment: If to remove `Try` block during decoding invalid color exception will be re-thrown instead of `JsError` result returned.

Comment: @RubenVerg I removed `Try` and all logic and see as the result: `Options(java.awt.Color[r=171,g=205,b=239])
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "invalid_color"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)`

Comment: ok. crashing works just fine in my use-case, but thanks anyways for showing advanced error handling stuff

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229658/discussion-between-ivan-kurchenko-and-rubenverg).